# Prevent 'stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString' overriding

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8

I have this code:

```
NSString *formatted = original;
formatted = [original stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B"];
formatted = [original stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
```

As you may be able to see, I am trying to do the following:

1. '+' is replaced with '%2B'
2. ' ' is replaced with '+'

Of course, this is not working as the second line overrides the first line, so now only ' ' is being replaced with '+', with the first line of code being ineffective.

Is there a workaround to this?

Comment: Just run the second line on the output of the first, instead of on `original`.

Comment: @Hotlicks If you are trying to say switch the 2nd and 3rd lines of code around, this does not work as it ends up ignoring the former line. The answers to my question have been sufficient.

Comment: No, I'm saying that rather than running the second line and throwing the results of that away when you run the 3rd line, use the output of one as the input of the other.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *formatted = original;
formatted = [formatted stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B"];
formatted = [formatted stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
```

Comment: If you have any problem, you can use new NSString, to do things in more clear way: NSString *firstSept=....., NSString *secondStep =...., NSString *result=..... ?

Comment: More effective? It make this and more work, you can read this: "The NSMutableString class adds one primitive method—replaceCharactersInRange:withString:—to the basic string-handling behavior inherited from NSString." In Apple documentations, and you can use Profile.

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution:

```
NSString *original = @"some string+here";

NSString *formatted = [original stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B"];
formatted = [formatted stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];

NSLog(@"formatted: %@", formatted);
```

Output:

> formatted: some+string%2Bhere

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am quite confused now with which approach to go with, whether to use a mutable or immutable object..

Comment: In general use immutable, it is safer. Interestingly the mutable answer is more code and more code is not a good thing.  Best practice #1 is write the most clear code possible ignoring optimizations. Later if there are performance issues then profile, find the exact problem and optimize. Very little code causes a performance problem.

Comment: @RAStudios i'll read up on [premature optimization](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil) then take a look at your code and see what fits best

Answer (score -1):

The best approach is to use a [Mutable string](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/) object instead of a immutable object as each time you replace your string its has to create a new object in memory which results in bad coding practice.

```
   NSString *original = @"some string here";

    /**
     *  Create a Mutable string object as you will always be changing its value depending on the request
     */
    NSMutableString *newString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:original];

    /**
     *  replace all occurrences within the current object
     */
    [newString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"+"
                               withString:@"%2B"
                                  options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, newString.length)];

    [newString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@" "
                               withString:@"+"
                                  options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, newString.length)];

    NSLog(@"Result: %@", newString);
```

Comment: Actually using `NSString` is a best practice.

Comment: @Zaph Really can you explain your reason? this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7275097/when-should-we-use-nsstring-and-nsmutablestring) say otherwise

Comment: @ShamsAhmed I believe the link question says that `NSMutableString` is more effective memory wise, here is a quote: _"I expect MutableString will be slightly more efficient in terms of memory as you are indicating early on that the program may need memory dynamically. NSString is likely to be allocated a single, suitably sized block of memory."_

Comment: 1. Coding for efficiency is pre-mature optimization. 2. There is an assumption that in a particular usage there is a performance increase. 3. It is unknown what is happening in the actual `NSString` code and what optimization there are. 4. Immutable objects can be passed without concern that a receiver will have the content changed by another method with a pointer to the same mutable object. 5. To quote [Donald Knuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth): "Premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming."

Comment: thanks for the information, in terms of point 1. judging from the question and code snippet optimization is some what justifiable. point 2. I have to admit its very arguable as there isn't much information on the performance increase, on apple documentation it does say it better for memory but doesn’t give a detailed explanation or benchmarks. point 3. that correct and point 4. that true but there will be overheads in memory

Comment: @ShamsAhmed You are making assumptions about the implementation. In particular changing "+" to "%2B" is not an in-place operation, there probably will be a new character array or character copying to make room. If you want to make an argument for using a mutable string create a test and provide results otherwise it is just a guess with no real basis.

Comment: @Zaph voting not a issue, only there best answer should be voted up and accepted...

Comment: @ShamsAhmed Yes, I agree. Unfortunately there are users here who will retaliate by randomly down voting good questions and answers of the person they think down voted an answer. That is the reason there are often no explanation offered to a down vote.