# NSMutableString performance

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to create a string. Based on condition I have to append some extra string. In this case which is preferred to use? Whether creating two different strings based on condition or creating mutable string to append a new string based on condition ?

EX

```
if(a==1)
{
    String = "apple seed" 
}
else
{
    String = "apple"
}
```

Or

```
NSMutableString *string ;

string = @"apple"; 

if( a==1)
{
    [string appendString:@"seed"]
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should we use NSString and NSMutableString?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7275097/when-should-we-use-nsstring-and-nsmutablestring)

Answer (score 1):

A string literal, like your `@"apple"`, is a compile-time constant so assigning a string literal to a variable of type `NSString *` is a cheap operation.

So *for your particular examples* the first selects one of two simple assignments, while the second can do a simple assignment and a method call - which is clearly going to take a little more time.

That said a "little more" on a modern computer is not long. Beware of optimising prematurely; it is far better to write code that is clear and understandable to you first and concern yourself over performance of minutiae later if needed (this is **not** an excuse to write poor algorithms or intentionally bad code of course).

HTH